# Delete first number only if it is 1 in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of numbers in Notepad++ that looks like this:

```
2445
3846
18374
3445
16467
```

How can I delete any preceding `1`s so that the result looks like this:

```
2445
3846
8374
3445
6467
```

Comment: You can open the file with python, read the data out of it, modify the data and paste it in the file again.

Comment: You could use the "Find" feature with a proper regular expression, bookmark those lines through the options, and then remove all lines that hold a bookmark

Answer (score 1):

Try finding this in regex mode:

```
^1.*\r?\n
```

And replace with empty string.

The above pattern just says to match any line which starts with 1, followed by anything and then a line ending (`\r?\n`).  By the way, you might be able to just use a slightly simplified pattern:

```
^1.*\R
```

The `\R` just means match a system independent line ending (i.e. either Windows or Unix).

Answer (score 0):

Use regex search & replace.

Search:

```
^1(.*)
```

Replace:

```
\1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet if you want to use notepad++ is to use regex replace.
Go to the find option Ctrl+F select replace and select `Regular Expression`

If your numbers are on the same line use a regex like
`\s1(\d+\s)`
replace with `$1` <-- notice the space at the beginning

If your numbers are on separate lines use a regex like
`\n1(\d+)$`

replace with 
`\n$1`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Search->Replace...]

Search->Replace... in menu notepad++

Answer (score 0):

- Find what: `^1`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>